# How to show logging stats in Python

Tags: python, logging

I want to know the summary of all the log in Python using the logging module. For example this stat from Scrapy.

```
{'crawlera/request': 699,
 'crawlera/request/method/GET': 671,
 'crawlera/request/method/POST': 28,
 'crawlera/response': 699,
 'crawlera/response/status/200': 364,
 'crawlera/response/status/301': 335,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 384460,
 'downloader/request_count': 699,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 671,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 28,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3804333,
 'downloader/response_count': 699,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 364,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 335,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 991.665077,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 5, 13, 50, 33, 105097),
 'item_scraped_count': 335,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1036,
 'log_count/INFO': 46,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 364,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 699,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 699,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 699,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 699,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 5, 13, 34, 1, 440020)}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Python 3.6v

This is one way you can create logs.

default log level is 0

LEVEL    VALUE

NonSet  = 0

DEBUG   = 10

INFO    = 20

WARNING = 30

ERROR   = 40

CRITICAL= 50

Set Log level using variable logger_level as per your need.

```
import logging 

def initiateLogger(logger_level):
    # create and configure logger
    file_name = r'logs.log'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_name, format='%(asctime)s  %(levelname)s--%(message)s', filemode='w')

    # Creating an object
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # set logging level
    logger.setLevel(logger_level)
    logger.info(f'logging level:{logger_level}')

#call func
initiateLogger('INFO')
```